# SSIS package with Analysis service source is failing in the validation phase

Tags: sql-server, validation, ssis, oledb, mdx

I have a SSIS package that pulls data from a multidimensional cube. I am using MDX query which is taking date value as a parameter from a SQL task. I am using a variable to pass that value to the MDX query. Also, I am using SQL command from variable as data access mode in the OLE DB Source. In the validation phase(delay validation is enabled), it is failing throwing the following error: 
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "OLE DB Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".
I have tried all possible solutions here and other sources on web but none of them seems to work. Did anyone come across such issue before?
It is running fine when I hard code the parameter value through a dummy variable.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?   This error is usually on subsequent components after the metadata in the source has changed.   Are there any other errors or warnings accompanying that error?   You might need to scrap and rebuild the source component.

Comment: Try putting in a script task and get the MDX query it is generating. Take that query and paste and run it on SSMS. That should help you in locating the error.